# Django: While keeping debug=True APIs are running faster

Tags: django

I have observed that our production environment is slow while keeping

`debug=False`

We need to wait 20s or 15 sec for one API response.

The same API's are performing in milliseconds, only we changed

```
debug=True
```

Comment: Do you have any code that changes settings like database connections based on the debug being set? Like a dev mode or something?

Comment: No we don't have

Comment: What are you using for your APIs?

Comment: Django Rest Framework

Comment: Did you run the production environment using Django's built-in server? Django doesn't server static files when `debug=False`.

Comment: We are using gunicorn and nginx for hosting the application